# Might I enquire of you what "cut toward" means?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

> I was about to run toward the goal so Mark could pass the ball to me,
>   but he looked me off. So instead I fell back and let Jenny **cut toward**
>   the goal. Mark passed to Jenny and she scored!

Although I'm not sure of it, I'd conjecture that that would mean  "moved speedily toward". Would you tell me what that means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means change direction, so Jenny changed direction with the ball and then scored.

She could also have “cut right” toward the goal.

This is another meaning that has a nautical basis as there is the term “to cut and run” but that is to cut ropes so they can leave in a hurry, due to older shops sailing with the wind....